# lm() Regression with interactions for an entire dataframe

Tags: r, regression, lm

I know there is a shortcut in `R`to run an `lm()`regression on all a dataframe like this :

```
reg<-lm(y~.,data=df)
```

With df having explanatory variables x1, x2, ... x5, so it is the same as writing

```
reg<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,data=df)
```

But this doesn't include interactions terms like x1:x2, ... Is there a shortcut in `R`to run a regression on all columns of a dataframe with the interactions ?
I am looking for 2 shortcuts which will have the same effects as

```
reg<-lm(y~x1*x2,x1*x3,x1*x4,x1*x5,x2*x3,...)
reg<-lm(y~x1*x2*x3*x4*x5) # this one will have interactions between the 5 variables
```

Comment: What do you mean with a shortcut? \

Comment: the same way lm(y~.) is a shortcut to lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5), something which will allow me not to write all my variables in lm().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For both you could use the `^` operator.

See the example:

In your first case you just need the pair-wise interactions (2-way interactions). So you could do:

```
#Example df
df <- data.frame(a=runif(1:100), b=runif(1:100), c=runif(1:100), d=runif(1:100))

> lm(a ~ (b+c+d)^2, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ (b + c + d)^2, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b            c            d          b:c          b:d          c:d  
    0.53873      0.23531      0.07813     -0.14763     -0.43130      0.11084      0.13181
```

As you can see the above produced the pair-wise interactions

Now in order to include all the interactions you can do:

```
> lm(a ~ (b+c+d)^5 , data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ (b + c + d)^5, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b            c            d          b:c          b:d          c:d        b:c:d  
    0.54059      0.23123      0.07455     -0.15150     -0.42340      0.11926      0.14017     -0.01803
```

In this case you just need to use a number greater than the number of variables you will use (in this case I use 5 but it could be anything greater than 3). As you see all the interactions are produced.

Comment: Have a look at [this website](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html). Here are all the interactions mentioned. Including the ones from @LyzandeR.

Comment: Why exponent of 5? I was thinking 3.

Answer (score 18):

The shortcut you are searching for is:

```
reg <- lm(y ~ (.)^2, data = df)
```

This will create a model with the main effects and the interactions between regressors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Remove the asterisks, they are basically useless there and potentially harmful.